# Scraped website data is not being written to a CSV

Tags: python, selenium, csv, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape a website to get the info and output it to a CSV file. For the data I am trying to extract, there is an output to the terminal but I need that to be in a CSV file.

I have tried several different methods but cannot find a solution.
The CSV file is created but it's just empty. There is probably something really simple.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import csv
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/jasonbeedle/Desktop/snaviescraper/chromedriver'

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'

# Navigate to url
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("http://best4sport.tv/2hd/2020-12-10/")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
results = driver.find_element_by_class_name('program1_content_container')
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, 'html.parser')

# results = driver.find_element_by_class_name('program1_content_container')
p_data1 = soup.find_all("div", {"class_name": "program1_content_container"})
p_data2 = soup.find_all("div", {"class_name": "program_time"})
p_data3 = soup.find_all("div", {"class_name": "sport"})
p_data4 = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "program_text"})

print("Here is your data, I am off ot sleep now see ya ")
print(results.text)
# Create csv
programme_list = []
# Programme List
for item in p_data1:
    try:
        name = item.contents[1].find_all(
            "div", {"class": "program1_content_container"})[0].text
    except:
        name = ''

    p_data1 = [time]
    programme_list.append(p_data1)

# Programme Time
for item in p_data2:
    try:
        time = item.contents[1].find_all(
            "div", {"class": "program_time"})[0].text
    except:
        time = ''

    p_data2 = [time]
    programme_list.append(p_data2)

# Which sport
for item in p_data3:
    try:
        time = item.contents[1].find_all(
            "div", {"class": "sport"})[0].text
    except:
        time = ''

    p_data3 = [time]
    programme_list.append(p_data3)

with open('sport.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in programme_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I have just tried to add an object called `data_output` Then I tried to print the `data_output`

```
data_output = [p_data1, p_data2, p_data3, p_data4]
...
print(data_output)
```

The output in the terminal is

Comment: how does the `programme_list` variable looks like when it is filled with values?

Comment: `19:55
MOTORU SPORTS
Motoru sporta "5 minūte"
Iknedēļas Alda Putniņa veidots apskats par motoru sportu
20:00
BASKETBOLS
CSKA pret Zielona Gora
VTB Vienotās līgas 2020./2021. gada regulārās sezonas spēle (08.12.2020.)
22:00
BASKETBOLS`

Comment: Can you share your url if public? you could use `pandas` to to load data into `dataframe` and then export to csv file.

Comment: http://best4sport.tv/2hd/2020-12-10/ I have never used Pandas will look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load data into  pandas `dataframe` and export into csv.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/jasonbeedle/Desktop/snaviescraper/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("http://best4sport.tv/2hd/2020-12-10/")
results =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".program1_content_container")))
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.get_attribute("outerHTML"), 'html.parser')
program_time=[]
sport=[]
program_text=[]
program_info=[]
for item in soup.select(".program_details "):
    if item.find_next(class_='program_time'):
        program_time.append(item.find_next(class_='program_time').text.strip())
    else:
        program_time.append("Nan")
    if item.find_next(class_='sport'):
        sport.append(item.find_next(class_='sport').text.strip())
    else:
        sport.append("Nan")
    if item.find_next(class_='program_text'):
        program_text.append(item.find_next(class_='program_text').text.strip())
    else:
        program_text.append("Nan")
    if item.find_next(class_='program_info'):
        program_info.append(item.find_next(class_='program_info').text.strip())
    else:
        program_info.append("Nan")

df=pd.DataFrame({"program_time":program_time,"sport":sport,"program_text":program_text,"program_info":program_info})
print(df)
df.to_csv("sport.csv")
```

---

csv snapshot after creation

[image]

If you don't have pandas then you need to install it.

> pip install pandas

Comment: I think I love you. Thank you so much!!! SO should have awards like Reddit.

Comment: @JasonBeedle : Glad to able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing binary, can you try changing wb to w?

Change

```
with open('sport.csv', 'wb') as file:
```

to

```
with open('sport.csv', 'w') as file:
```

**EDITED:**

Sorry for being a bit late. Here is the code modified based on your original code FYI.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import csv
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/jasonbeedle/Desktop/snaviescraper/chromedriver'

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'

# Navigate to url
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("http://best4sport.tv/2hd/2020-12-10/")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
results = driver.find_element_by_class_name('program1_content_container')
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# results = driver.find_element_by_class_name('program1_content_container')
p_data1 = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "program_info"})
p_data2 = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "program_time"})
p_data3 = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "sport"})
p_data4 = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "program_text"})

# Create csv
programme_list = []
# Programme List
for i in range(len(p_data1)):
    programme_list.append([p_data1[i].text.strip(), p_data2[i].text.strip(), p_data3[i].text.strip(), p_data4[i].text.strip()])
    
with open('sport.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["program_info", "program_time", "sport", "program_text"])
    for row in programme_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Excel Screenshot here
[image]

Comment: Could you share the program with us so we could help you identify the bug?

Comment: Added the code into the code block within the question

Answer (score 1):

As Blue Fishy said you can try to change to w mode only, but you may run in an encoding error.

**Solution that works on your data**

```
import csv 

programme_list = ['19:55','MOTORU SPORTS','Motoru sporta "5 minūte"','Iknedēļas Alda Putniņa veidots apskats par motoru sportu','20:00','BASKETBOLS','...']

with open('sport.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    for row in programme_list:
        print(row)
        writer.writerow([row])
```

**Output**

```
19:55
MOTORU SPORTS
"Motoru sporta ""5 minūte"""
Iknedēļas Alda Putniņa veidots apskats par motoru sportu
20:00
BASKETBOLS
...
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want. Although I need to take that extracted data and populate the programme_list = [ ]